# Distinct Prime Partitions in Prolog

Tags: prolog, computer-science, primes, clpfd

I need to enumerate all the ways of partitioning a given number n into a sum of one or more distinct primes, a + b + ... + m in Prolog

For example:

Given an integer n, the program should write the appropriate sums to standard output. If n = 20, for example, the program might print

```
2 + 5 + 13
2 + 7 + 11
3 + 17
7 + 13
```

n can be any number, and there is no restriction on run-time.

Here is what I have:

```
partition(N, _, []) :- N = 0.
partition(N, [], _) :- fail.

partition(N, [IH|IT], [OH|OT]) :-
    N =< 0, fail;
    N >= IH, M is N-IH, OH = IH,
    partition(M, [IH|IT], OT).

partition(N, [_|IT], Output) :-
    N =< 0, fail;
    partition(N, IT, Output).

partition(N, Output) :-
    generatePrime(N,L),
    partition(N, L, Output).

generatePrime(1, []) :- !.
generatePrime(N, X) :-
    not(isPrime(N)), !,
    Z is N-1,
    generatePrime(Z,X).
generatePrime(N, [N | X]) :-
    Z is N-1,
    generatePrime(Z,X).

isPrime(2).
isPrime(P) :-
    P > 2,
    isDivisible(P, P-1). 

isDivisible(P,X) :-
    X > 1,
    P mod X =\= 0,
    isDivisible(P, X-1).
isDivisible(_, X) :-
    1 is X.
```

Currently, I try running something like this:

[?- partition(5, X).

and I get duplicate prompts of [5] and [3,2]. There is also another type of problem when I use bigger numbers like n = 20, as I get prompts with duplicate primes like [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2].

I am very new to prolog, and I am sure there might even be an easier way of doing this problem, but I'm not sure where I am tripping up in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not so far...

The bigger problem is the way your'r calling `partition/3`

```
partition(5, generatePrime(5,Y), X)
```

`partition/3` expect a list for the second term, not `generatePrime(5, Y)`.

I suggest you to add a `partition/2` made as follows

```
partition(N, Output) :-
    generatePrime(N, L),
    partition(N, L, Output).
```

and call this version of `partition`

```
partition(5, X)
```

There is something else wrong because this call return more time the same response (return, in `X`, `[5]` four times and `[3,2]` two times).

I'll give a look at it to see if I see the problem

***--- EDIT ---***

Sorry but I have big problems understandign Prolog code with cuts (`!`), `fail` and or (`;`).

It's a problem of mine, I suppose.

I've modified your `partition/3` in the following way

```
partition(0, _, []).

partition(N, [H | It], [H | Ot]) :-
   N >= H,
   M is N-H,
   partition(M, [H | It], Ot).

partition(N, [_ | It], O) :-
   N > 0, 
   partition(N, It, O).
```

This should avoid repetitions of lists

If you want avoid duplicate primes in the same list (if you don't accept `[3, 3, 2]` or `[2, 2, 2, 2]` for 8 because a prime repeated), you should avoid to reuse `H` (`IH` in your original code) in the following call to `partition/3`.

I mean that the following clause

```
partition(N, [H | It], [H | Ot]) :-
   N >= H,
   M is N-H,
   partition(M, [H | It], Ot).
```

should become

```
partition(N, [H | It], [H | Ot]) :-
   N >= H,
   M is N-H,
   partition(M, It, Ot).
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I will edit the question accordingly. I also noticed that when I used a number like 20, I have the duplicate answers like you said, but also non-distinct prime answers like [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2].

Comment: @Ganda - modified my anser to show how to avoid duplication (of lists of of primes in lists).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relatively efficient answer, using [**`library(clpfd)`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) in SWI-Prolog.

*you will need `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).` at the beginning of your program.*

#### The main predicate: `partition/2`

This predicate can be described in a very simple manner:

```
partition(N,Z) :-
    findall(P, (P in 2..N, prime(P)), L),
    findall(S, ordered_subset_sum(L, S, N), Z).
```

In short: find all numbers `P` in `[2,N]` such that they are primes. We store those primes in the list `L`.

Then, we check that summing an ordered subset `S` of `L` results in `N`, using a predicate `ordered_subset_sum/3`. We store the valid subsets in `Z`, which is our output.

#### `ordered_subset_sum/3`

```
ordered_subset_sum([],[],0).
ordered_subset_sum([H|T],[H|T2],N) :-
     M #= N - H,
     M #>= 0,
    ordered_subset_sum(T,T2,M).
ordered_subset_sum([_|T],T2,N) :-
    ordered_subset_sum(T,T2,N).
```

- Base case: an empty list can only generate an empty subset ; the sum of the elements of the empty subset is `0`.
- Second clause: we keep `H`, the head of the list, in the subset ; thus the sum that we want to reach `N` is decreased by `H`, resulting in `M`. If `M` is negative, then we already know that the subset cannot sum to `N` ; it is too big.
- Third clause: we ignore the head of the list, allowing the generation of subsets.

#### `prime/1`

You can reuse your predicate `isPrime` if you wish, as such:

```
prime(N) :-
    indomain(N),
    isPrime(N).
```

But I would recommend using a more efficient prime checking algorithm. I propose the following one, which is far from optimal but much more efficient than yours. It checks that the prime decomposition of your number only has one element (only prime numbers do). You could also look at [Julio Di Egidio's Prime-Prolog library](https://github.com/jp-diegidio/Nan.Numerics.Prime-Prolog).

```
prime(N) :-
    prime_decomposition(N,[_P]).

prime_decomposition(N, Z) :-
    N #> 0,
    indomain(N),
    prime_decomposition_ceiled_square_root(N,SN),
    prime_decomposition_1(N, SN, 2, [], Z).
 
prime_decomposition_1(1, _, _, L, L) :- !.
prime_decomposition_1(N, SN, D, L, LF) :-
    (   
        0 #= N mod D ->
        Q #= N // D,
        prime_decomposition_ceiled_square_root(Q,SQ),
        prime_decomposition_1(Q, SQ, D, [D |L], LF)
        ;
        D1 #= D+1,
        (    
            D1 #> SN ->
            LF = [N |L]
            ;
            prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D1, L, LF)
        )
    ).
    
prime_decomposition_2(1, _, _, L, L) :- !.
prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D, L, LF) :-
    (   
        0 #= N mod D ->
        Q #= N // D,
        prime_decomposition_ceiled_square_root(Q,SQ),
        prime_decomposition_2(Q, SQ, D, [D |L], LF);
        D1 #= D+2,
        (    
            D1 #> SN ->
            LF = [N |L]
            ;
            prime_decomposition_2(N, SN, D1, L, LF)
        )
    ).
    
prime_decomposition_ceiled_square_root(0, 0).
prime_decomposition_ceiled_square_root(N0, Root) :-
        N1 #= N0 - 1,
        Max in 0..N1,
        R0^2 #= Max,
        Root #= Root0 + 1,
        fd_sup(R0, Root0).
```